# Can not activate Hyper-V on windows features

Tags: docker, hyper-v, windows-11

I cannot enable Hyper-V in windows features:

I am trying to enable Hyper-V on my Windows 11 Pro. I can check the Hyper-V box in Windows Features, but after restarting the computer, the box is unchecked again in Windows Features.

I have also tried to do this through Powershell as an administrator and that was unsuccessful as well. All suggested solutions did not work. After several hours I am now quite clueless....

Does anyone have a good idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure to enable all virtualization features in the BIOS? VT-d and similar stuff if there?

Comment: Yes, the virtualization feature is activated

Comment: Hum, difficult one, I would install Docker and use it's installer helper to find any missing packages you might need (Docker asks for a Windows Update that needs to be installed sometimes to enable Hyper-V).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use DISM to enable it with this command in **elevated CMD or Powershell**

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

This command should also enable Hyper-V **(Powershell only)**

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

I hope this works for you!